# Adding new line using StringBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net, stringbuilder

I want to send user an email as below:
Here is the Verification Code
UserName: xyz
Code: xyz

Here is my all code about email:

```
StringBuilder emailMessage = new StringBuilder();
emailMessage.Append("Here is the Verification Code.");
emailMessage.Append(Environment.NewLine);
emailMessage.Append("UserName: " + UsernameTextBox.Text).AppendLine();
emailMessage.AppendLine();
emailMessage.Append("Code:  " + newCode);
MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
email.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailAddress));
email.Subject = "Subject";
email.Body = emailMessage.ToString();
email.IsBodyHtml = true;
  //Send Email; 
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(email);
```

This code sends mail with a single line i.e. Here is the verification code. UserName: xyz Code: xyx
I tried using `emailMessage.Append(Environment.NewLine);` I also tried `"\n"`, `\r\n` but nothing worked. what's wrong with it or where am I missing something?

Comment: in what format do you send the email? if it is nby HTML, you need proper HTML tags like <br/>, if via text the appendline should work properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `AppendLine()` when adding to the stringbuilder

[StringBuilder.AppendLine Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

EDIT:

If you are building HTML for the email then you need to append `<br />`. This will add a break and create a new line for you.

Comment: +0: It is unlikely to help as appending new line will have about the same effect. Most likely OP trying to build HTML and as result when it rendered all new line/whitespaces are ignored.

Comment: Then the OP should state that he is building HTML

Comment: I tried ``AppendLine()`` as you can see in 5th line of code, its not working

Comment: Are you building HTML then?

Comment: yes ``MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
                    email.Body = emailMessage.ToString();
                    email.IsBodyHtml = true;``

Answer (score 2):

The answer of your question is, use `AppendLine()` method. But as you are sending email I would strongly recommended you to create a HTML template which contains the placeholder for actual value and then replace the placeholder with actual values and then send that content to the email body with `IsBodyHtml=true`.

This will help you in future as well like when you want to change the format of the email you don't need to build or deploy your project, you just need to edit the template.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplate/template.htm")));

 //Replace literals
 sb.Replace("<%Name%>", "FirstName");
 sb.Replace("<%EmailAddress%>", "Email");
 sb.Replace("<%Password%>", "password");
```

Answer (score 1):

For HTML email you want to use `<br />` instead of `\n`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<br/>` tag and set/add the Content `AlternateViews` `text/html`

```
AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlContent);
htmlView.ContentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html");
<MailMessageObject>.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebk18257.aspx)

```
  StringBuilder emailMessage = new StringBuilder();
                    emailMessage.AppendLine("Here is the Verification Code.");
                   // emailMessage.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    emailMessage.AppendLine("UserName: " + UsernameTextBox.Text);
                    emailMessage.AppendLine();
                    emailMessage.AppendLine("Code:  " + newCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

an extension method could simplify code...

```cs
public static StringBuilder AppendHtmlLine(this StringBuilder sb, string line) {
    return sb.Append(line + "<br>");
}
```

then you just call

```cs
stringBuilder.AppendHtmlLine("Here is the Verification Code.");
```

and lines will be terminated with `<br>`